# list indices must be integers, not str Error on Zapier

Tags: zapier, facebook-ads, salesforce

Creating a lead in Salesforce. Get this error.

`list indices must be integers, not str`

[image]

I have tested the steps of the Zap. Re-done each field pulling in Salesforce.

When I google this, it is a Python error, which Zapier uses. Is this something I can fix on my side?

Answer (score 2):

This was a temporary bug that has since been fixed. You should be able to replay any tasks that failed due to this error.